# Cmdlet in PowerShell to display certain groups

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to use the `Get-Verb` command in PowerShell and route only the "Common" verbs to output. However I've tried a bunch of different combinations I used a while ago that will not work now. What would be the easiest way to just display the "common verbs"?

Answer (score 2):

Something like

```
get-verb | where {$_.group -eq 'common'}
```

?

Comment: Thank you! Just curious; What does the $_. indicate. I understand its looking for the group "common". Why doesn't where -group "common" work?

Comment: See get-help where-object.  The where clause is basically a boolean test. If it resolves to $true, the object goes on down the pipeline. If it resolves to $false the object gets discarded. $_ represents to object currently in the pipeline being tested (see get-help about_pipeline).